# Is there a way to compare 2 process builder?

Tags: process-builder

I have 2 version of the same process builder I want to compare. I need to know what changed in one.
One was changed in production, and the other was changed in a sandbox.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could use sfdx or ant to retrieve it as XML (flow) for specific version, and then compare XML files to see what was changed in each scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using developer tools by pulling or retrieving the process builder's meta definition, using SFDX or tooling that uses the Metadata API, from each org then use any file comparison tool such as WinDiff, kdiff3, your IDE (VSCode or IntelliJ IDEA etc.) or something else like that.

These files look a bit like this:

[image: Process Builder XML]

They are actually held as Flows in the metadata definition, so appear in the flows folder and are named Xyz.flow-meta.xml.

The content is somewhat technical so you may have difficulty interpreting it, depending on what type of job role or level of technical knowledge you have.

Comment: `The content is somewhat technical so you may have difficulty interpreting it` - someday, I hope, there will be a diff viewer that shows things graphically between PB or Flow versions that a PR approver can actually exploit

Comment: @cropredy, before that, I'd like the flow editor to allow me to change element linkage when I need to refactor a flow; copying the elements, deleting the originals and pasting the copy in the new position in the flow is not robust (I've had variable references break when copying the element that generates the variable, for example). Once that's working I'd be happy with a visual diff tool :D